# Cassandra Fast Read Configuration

Tags: cassandra

I have 4 Cassandra nodes with 1 seed in a single data center. I have about 5M records in which Cassandra takes around 4 mins to read where with MySQL, it takes only 17 seconds. So my guess is that there is something wrong in my configuration. So kindly will anyone let me know what configuration attributes so I have to check in Cassandra.yaml.

Comment: How are the records partitioned across the nodes? Are you requesting all 5M records in a single query?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, regarding partitions I am using "Murmur3Partitioner" with defaults.  What I am doing is that I am loading all of the data into a BI tool, namely, Qlik. So to answer to your question yes.

Answer (score 1):

You may be doing an apples to oranges comparison if you are reading all 5M records from one client.

With MySQL all the data is local and optimized for reads since data is updated in place.

Cassandra is distributed and optimized for writes.  Writes are simple appends, but reads are expensive since all the appends need to be read and merged to get the current value of each column.

Since the data is distributed across multiple nodes, there is a lot of overhead of accessing and retrieving the data over the network.

If you were using Spark with Cassandra and loading the data into Spark workers in parallel without shuffling it across the network to a single client, then it would be a more similar comparison.

Cassandra is generally good at ingesting large amounts of data and then working on small slices of it (i.e. partitions) rather than doing table scan operations such as reading the entire table.

Comment: Cassandra is NoSQL means read is straightforward. We have partition key on cassandra to distribute data among nodes some with MYSQL Sharding. So it may depends on replication factor and consistency level